# Quais são os riscos em usar Singleton no java

Tags: java, android

Olá,
Quais são os riscos de erro ao usar a prática Singleton em java? estou usando o seguinte:

```
private Os mInstance = null;
private int numeroOs, updateServer;
Context context;

    public synchronized Os getInstance(Context c,  int numeroOs) {
        context = c;
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new Os(context.getApplicationContext(), numeroOs);
        }

        return mInstance;
    }

    protected Os(Context context, int numeroOs) {
        this.numeroOs = numeroOs;
        this.context = context;
    }
```

Quando devo instanciar a classe Os (do ex.) para setar os parâmetros de entrada "context e numeroOs"? e se ela não for instanciada o que acontecerá?

Comment: Risco? Modelagem errada é um risco alto

Comment: Acho que só o fato de estar usando e não saber o risco já é um grande risco.

Comment: Esse seu caso não seria um multiton?